# Docx4j: Get stylename of paragraph

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I want to parse a docx document. I use this code to get the paragraphs and display the text:

```
   final String XPATH_TO_SELECT_TEXT_NODES = "//w:p";
    final List<Object> jaxbNodes = documentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(XPATH_TO_SELECT_TEXT_NODES, true);

    for (Object jaxbNode : jaxbNodes){
            final String paragraphString = jaxbNode.toString();
            System.out.println("[Start]: " + paragraphString);
    }
```

But i also need to know the stylename of the current paragraph. How can i do this?

Thanks for your help.
1ceman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PPr pPr = ((P) XmlUtils.unwrap(jaxbNode)).getPPr();

if (pPr != null) {
    PPrBase.PStyle pStyle = pPr.getPStyle();

    if (pStyle != null) {
        String style = pStyle.getVal();
    }
}
```

If there is no explicit style, then it uses the default paragraph style (as specified in the styles part).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. it works great. Is there a difference between the code above and 'Ppr pPr = ((P)jaxbNode).getPPr()' ?

Comment: Probably not.  P should never be wrapped in a JAXBElement; ObjectFactory's createP just creates a bare P object.